# What is the probability that $Y_n \leq 0$ if $Y = AX$ and we know the CDF of $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, limits

Let $X$ be a $n$ dimensional random vector and $Y = AX$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ invertible matrix. Suppose we know the CDF of $X$. Then what is $P(Y_n \leq 0)$?

My attempt was make a vector $y =(y_1,...,y_{n-1},0)$ then take the following limit
\begin{align*}
P(Y_n \leq 0) &= P(Y_1\leq +\infty,...,Y_{n-1}\leq +\infty,Y_n\leq 0)
\\
&= \lim_{y_1,...,y_{n-1}\to\infty}P(Y\leq y)
\\
&=\lim_{y_1,...,y_{n-1}\to\infty}P(X \leq A^{-1}y)
\end{align*}
But then I run into the problem of finding the limit 
$$\lim_{y_1,...,y_{n-1}\to\infty}A^{-1}y$$
Depending on which paths $y_1,...,y_{n-1}$ take in the limit we may get very different answers. For instance if we take the limit along $y_1=y_2$ that may be different than the limit along $y_1 = 2y_2$

Comment: No, $Ax \le y$ is not the same as $x \le A^{-1} y$, unless $A$ happens to be a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements.

Comment: Hmm I hadn’t thought of that. Should I be applying the transformation A to the pdf of X then. Something like p_Y(y) =p_X(A^{-1}y)?

Comment: You should be transforming the pdf, but that's not quite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the formula for the pdf of a transformed random vector
$$f_Y(y) = f_X(A^{-1}y)|A^{-1}|$$
and then we integrate to get the CDF
$$P(Y\leq 0) = \int_{-\infty}^0 f_Y(y)dy = \frac{1}{|A|}\int_{-\infty}^0 f_X(A^{-1}y)dy $$